# autosuggestion is not working in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate localities auto suggestion in below url:

```
https://qa.roofandfloor.com/
```

I wrote the below code, but it is not working:

```
WebElement toElement = Driver.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='s2id_autogen1']"));

toElement.sendKeys("ye");
toElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Also, I need to test it for 5 entries, how to do that in an optimised way?

Comment: Refer to these links .see if it helps . Here there are some solutions to work with auto complete

http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/working-with-ajax-or-jquery-auto-complete-text-box-using-webdriver

http://nagarjunreddykasu.blogspot.in/2014/01/select-auto-suggest-on-search-field-for_16.html

Comment: SO editorial practices **require** that you put the code that is relevant to your question inside the body of the question itself. Links to provide **additional** information are allowed, provided that they do **not** replace the code that is relevant to your question. If you have too much code, this is a sign that you should create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The link to the external web site should be replaced with enough information for readers to know how the autocomplete operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is very much of an *asynchronous nature*.

This means that you would need to *explicitly wait for the elements to become present, visible, clickable etc*.

Here is an example code that would wait for the input with `id="s2id_autogen1"` to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
WebElement localities = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("s2id_autogen1")));

localities.sendKeys("ye");
localities.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: WebElement w = Driver.driver.findElement(proj_drop);
  w.sendKeys("ye"); 
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.driver, 5);
  WebElement localities = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("s2id_autogen1")));
  localities.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); 
this works perfectly..